# Learning Python lists, tuples

Tags: python

I'm learning Python and I'm trying to dive in and I want to fetch information on when files were created and modified in home directories for multiple users.

So far, I'm having trouble with the syntax while I'm trying to add multiple users to the list. If there's one user, then the script works fine, however, I'd like to be able to add multiple users.

```
import os.path
import time
import string

users = ['user1']
test = ' '.join(users)

for i in test:
    file = '/Users/'+test+'/sync.log'

print("created: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getctime(file)))
print("last modified: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(file)))
```

When it fails, I try to add more users e.g.

```
users = ['user1', 'user2']
```

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated to your question but the '%' operator on strings is a bit archaic.  str.format() is more common now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to join the two elements of the list together into a single string. You want to iterate over the elements of the list:

```
for user in users:
    file = '/Users/' + user + '/sync.log'
    print("created: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getctime(file)))
    print("last modified: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(file)))
```